# How to Change CartoDB Torque Cat Map Slider Range

Tags: carto, torque

Map slider range includes 83 month/years (2017, 2018, and 2019 are not there) but actual data only has 57 month/years see: https://sildeag.cartodb.com/viz/1e7ee1c6-0cbc-11e6-9822-0e787de82d45/map

Is there any way for a non-programmer to alter this behaviour so that slider range is for actual data values only using the "free" version?